# why is outer variable not available in if conditional

Tags: javascript, if-statement, scope

```
function NumStuff(num) {
    this.num = num;
    this.multipleOfFour = function() {

        //if multiple of 4
        if (this.num % 4 === 0) {
            console.log(this.num + " is a multiple of Four");
            console.log("the structure of the given integer " +
                this.num + " is ");

            for (let i = 0; i < this.num; i++) {
                if (4 * i === this.num) { //why is this.num outside of 
                    //lexical scope
                    console.log(this.num + " = " + i + " x 4");
                    break;
                }
            }
            //if not a multiple of 4
        } else {
            console.log(this.num + " isn't a multiple of 4 but here is the integer's structure:");
            let remainder = this.num % 4;
            let tempNum = this.num - remainder;
            for (let i = 0; i < tempNum; i++) {
                if (4 * i === tempNum) {
                    console.log(this.num + " = " + i + " x 4 + " + remainder);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    };
}

let num = prompt("Enter an integer:");
let n = new NumStuff(num);
n.multipleOfFour();
```

Say we enter 20 as our num. It passes through the multipleOfFour() and hits the first if conditional. This.num(20) % 4 is equal to 0 so it passes.Then we loop through i to find what number times 4 is equal to 20. This.num is in the scope of the for statement but not in the scope of the inner if conditional of the for statement. Why is that so?

Comment: This is not related to scoping, `this` is context. Also the context only might change if the executed function changes, and that's not the case here, so whatever you are interpreting in your output, it is not caused by `this.num` being different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is in the scope. That's not the issue.

But `this.num` is a `string` (that's what `prompt` *always* returns) while `4 * i` is a `number`. And `4 * i === this.num` will *always* be false, regardless of what you enter when prompted.

Try this ([here](https://jsfiddle.net/hv51utz0/)):

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.num; i++) {
    console.log('x', 4 * i, this.num, 4 * i === this.num);
```

An easy fix is `let num = parseInt(prompt("Enter an integer:"));`.

Comment: nice so simple, forgot that prompt always returns a string....thank you